# Maui Blazor import javascript and run document ready

Tags: javascript, blazor, maui

I'm trying to import a javascript file and run the document ready on first render. I have this on my razor page.

```
private IJSObjectReference module;

protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
if (firstRender)
   {
       await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",
       "/assets/js/jquery.3.6.min.js",
       "/assets/js/jquery.3.6.min.js",
       "/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
       "/assets/js/imageloded.min.js",
       "/assets/js/counterup.js",
       "/assets/js/waypoint.js",
       "/assets/js/magnific.min.js",
       "/assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js",
       "/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js",
       "/assets/js/nice-select.min.js",
       "/assets/js/fontawesome.min.js",
       "/assets/js/owl.min.js",
       "/assets/js/slick-slider.min.js",
       "/assets/js/wow.min.js",
       "/assets/js/tweenmax.min.js",
       "/assets/js/main.js"
       );

       await module.InvokeVoidAsync("WHAT TO PUT HERE");
   }
```

}

```
async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
{
    if (module is not null)
    {
        await module.DisposeAsync();
    }
 }
```

My javascript is a simple

```
$(document).ready(function () {}
```

I don't know how to call the document ready function using the invokeasyncvoid.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your $(document).ready() function inside another function and put it in your InvokeVoidAsync()

like this:

```
function onDocumentReady() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
       
    });
}
```

and

```
await module.InvokeVoidAsync("onDocumentReady");
```